# How to detect a specific group of numbers in a column in excel

Tags: excel-formula

Ok so I have a group of numbers say for example (12, 28,14). I also have a column of numbers in Column A up to the 150th row. Each cell in column A can take numbers between 0 and 36. I would like a formular that would highlight to me anytime this pattern (12,28 14) occurs in the list of numbers. The number group could be arranged in any order say for eg 28,12,14 or 28,14,12 etc. i have tried but I would like this to be more dynamic. Thanks for any assistance.

Comment: In the future, it's better to try to give example data and desired result. For example, the actual question I want to ask is: Does each value in column A contain a specific number or a string like `"28,12,14"`? (I'm really asking you this question, but also telling you that you might have received your answer already if I (and others) were confident about what you're asking.)

Comment: Thank you for your contribution. Let me be clear. As stated, each row contains a number between 0 and 36. So as each number is entered into the cells, the sheet should identify anytime the pattern 12,28,14 occurs within the 150 items in the range. As said it can follow any order like 28,12,14 or 14,12,28 etc. Thanks

Comment: I am new here so would give examples next time :-) But I hope my brief explanation is clear now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have numbers in cells A1:A150, type this formula in cell B3 and copy into cells B4:B150:

=IF(AND(NOT(ISNA(MATCH(A1,{12,14,28},0))),NOT(ISNA(MATCH(A2,{12,14,28},0))),NOT(ISNA(MATCH(A3,{12,14,28},0)))))

Returns TRUE if you get the three numbers in any order, FALSE otherwise.

You can customise the return values.  e.g.

=IF(AND(NOT(ISNA(MATCH(A1,{12,14,28},0))),NOT(ISNA(MATCH(A2,{12,14,28},0))),NOT(ISNA(MATCH(A3,{12,14,28},0)))), "Custom true", "Custom false")

Answer (score 0):

My first version of a solution would be to make five additional columns. Let's say you used columns B, C, D, E, and F for these new columns.

Also, identify your values to be matched against as a named range (e.g. 'ValuesToMatch') as well as another named range ('ValuesToMatchCount') that points to one cell with a formula of `=COUNT(ValuesToMatch)` You had said you wanted it to be dynamic, and this allows you to change set of values to match and the count will change automatically.

Assuming a set of 12,12,12 isn't good, we can check for that first. B2 would have a formula of `=COUNTA(UNIQUE(OFFSET(A2,0,0,ValuesToMatchCount,1)))=ValuesToMatchCount` to return true if the A2 is the start of a unique, nonblank set of values.

For column C, C2 should be `=COUNTIF(ValuesToMatch, A2)` to return 1 if A2 is a value in ValuesToMatch, otherwise 0.

And then column D would be true/false indicating whether or not this row was the beginning of a set we want, using a formula of `=AND(B2,SUM(OFFSET(C2,0,0, ValuesToMatchCount,1)=ValuesToMatchCount))` which returns true only if

- A2 is the beginning of a unique nonblank set of values, and
- All values in the set are within ValuesToMatch.

So if we drag these formulas down for all 150 rows, then any value in column A should be highlighted if column D is `TRUE` for that row OR the previous `ValuesToMatchCount - 1` rows, except that won't work for the first few rows. If we don't guard against this, row 2 will be trying to check rows, 2, 1, and 0! So we're going to use column E to calculate many rows, including the current row, to check for true values in column D. Assuming row 1 is used for column titles and row 2 is the first row of data, column E's formula should be `=MIN(ROW()-1,ValuesToMatchCount)`

And now, column F where F2 would have a formula of `=COUNTIF(OFFSET(D2,1-E2,0,E2,1),TRUE)>0` will return true for rows that are part of a set.

Once you have this you can hide columns B through F and your conditional formatting can highlight column A if the corresponding values in column F is true for that row.

Once you've debugged and tweaked this to your liking, then you could optionally try to combine a few of these columns together, if you like. But get it all working first. :-)